# Bringing HTML into JS to broadcast an image

Tags: javascript, html, connection, broadcast

I'm making a quiz for something. In the HTML there is a text box where the user can input their answer. I want to send it to JS to broadcast an image (a 'correct' image if correct, a 'wrong' image if wrong). This is the code so far relating to this problem.

Html

```
<input class="respBox" id="ans1" placeholder="Insert value of X here">
<p id="response1"></p>


<button type="button" class="specialButton" onclick="checkAnswers()">Submit</button>
```

JS
function checkAnswers() {

```
if (ans1 === "7.5") {// If x is 7.5
   response1 = rightAns;//rightAns is image for right answer
    document.getElementById('response1').innerHTML = response1;//updates scoring system 
   score++;//adds one point to the user's score
} else {
   response1 = wrongAns;//wrongAns is image for wrong answer
   document.getElementById('response1').innerHTML = response1;//updates scoring system  

   }}
```

I get this error message when I see website.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at checkAnswers

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="javascript:checkAnwsers()">
    <input class="respBox" name="answer" placeholder="Insert value of X here">
    <p id="response1"></p>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Put the input fields inside of a form element and action would be the function to call and name the input fields using attribute name

Use this for accessing the data in JavaScript:

```
var formElements = document.forms['myform'].elements['inputTypeName'].value;
```